# Coding a macro to organize large amounts of information

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to turn a long tedious process into a macro for work. The macro code below was generated from recording the aforementioned process, however, when I run the generated macros on the original information I do not get the correct result. Can anyone please help me?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Order No."
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C:C").Select
Sheets("data").Select
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheets("data").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheets("data").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheets("data").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheets("vybrané sloupce").Select
Range("L5499").Select
Range("L1").Select
Sheets("data").Select
Sheets("data").Select
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("M:AP").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("N1").Select
Sheets("vybrané sloupce").Select
Range("M1").Select
Sheets("data").Select
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("P6").Select
End Sub
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$12397").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "CONF-@", "CONF-MC", "CONF-PAY"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("A452").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$12158").AutoFilter Field:=2
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$12158").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "icprdv01", "ICPRMJ04", "ICPRPG01", "kowalska", "MONITORI01", "="),         Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=8
Range("B4").Select
End Sub
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Cancelled"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    "Atradius Quick Research"
Range("J2947").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
Range("J2947").Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("J4740").Select

End Sub
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=6
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "Atradius Initial Research"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    "CREDIT REPORT"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Cancelled"
Range("J3645").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
Range("J3645").Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("J4614").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=6
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$6445").AutoFilter Field:=2
End Sub
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Compare"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]<>RC[-1],""No Match"",""Match"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N6445"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("N2:N6445").Select
Range("N1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6445").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Match"
Range("J7").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Cancelled"
Range("J432").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
Range("J432").Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("J3790").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10
Range("N1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6445").AutoFilter Field:=14
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6445").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
    "Cancelled"
Range("A2718").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$6398").AutoFilter Field:=10
End Sub
```

The issue is only in part of macros 3, 4, and 5. Basically the code is failing to create the 'OK' filter in the status column even though it specifies to do so in the code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please describe the desired behavior and what actually happens when you run the code. `"I do not get the correct result"` is not very much to go on.

Comment: Since this is `to organize large financial information` I would suggest that your first step would be to get rid of that recorded macro and to starting learning VBA basics.

Comment: Here's a couple good VBA tutorials: [**Excel VBA For Complete Beginners**](http://www.homeandlearn.org/) and also [**HomeAndLearn.org Learning VBA**](http://www.homeandlearn.org/). .....also, using Recorded Macros to learn: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) and also [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: Thank you guys for responding to promptly - to clarify, the issue is only in part of macros 3, 4, 5. Basically the code is failing to create the 'OK' filter in the status column even though it specifies to do so in the code.

Comment: I can't see any 'OK' filter in your code,  you are just outputting 'OK into some cells in J column. It is difficult to advise if I don't know what exactly is desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

this is a pretty vague question, but if I understand that you are trying to apply a filter on a column for "OK" then I have used the following as a base.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="OK" 
'Change the range based on the column & num of rows in the column, this is set for column A
```

Hope this helps answer your question a bit.